# What kind of neural network is suitable for a card game?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

There is a ready application - a card game "Fool". Players connect to the server, connect in pairs, everything is fine, everything works. The client runs on Windows, UWP-application. Server - .NET, runs on Azure. Used by SignalR, for those who understand. There are no problems with all this.

What I want: make a bot for the game. Not stupid, but train him in the manner of playing the winning players. The server has all the information about every move during the game and who won at the end.

Question: What type of neural network (after all, do I need it, right?) is suitable for this specific task? What to google, where to dig? Well, like the roadmap: first read this, then this and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. Have a look at Minimax and Monte Carlo strategies - https://towardsdatascience.com/game-ais-with-minimax-and-monte-carlo-tree-search-af2a177361b0

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I'm slightly confused: cards games are not 'games of perfect information'. We don't know opponent's cards. We don't know next cards in the pile. So we can't suppose opponent's next move at all!

Comment: True. Although I've seen Minimax and MCTS used in context of multi-player games, for example here - https://project.dke.maastrichtuniversity.nl/games/files/phd/Nijssen_thesis.pdf